# How to separate price from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Application In PDF/JavaScript

I am trying to print the dollar values only from the array.
Tried the following and I am not sure If I am using the correction functions or not.

```js
var pdts = ['Apple*Fruits-$58.9', 'Orange*Fruits-$60.5'];
var arr = pdts.toString().split('-');

console.log(arr[2]);
console.log(arr);
```

Current Output:

```
$60.5
```

Expected output in different lines:

```
$58.9
$60.5
```

Please help

Comment: If it works, it's correct. :).  The rest is a lesson in efficiency and subjective opinion.

Comment: What is `console.println()`? The correct function is `console.log()`

Comment: console.println() is the replacement for console.log() in pdf applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the array, not convert the array to a single string.

```js
var pdts = ['Apple*Fruits-$58.9','Orange*Fruits-$60.5'];

result = pdts.map(pdt => pdt.split('-')[1]).join('\n');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could you please help me to add the join function also to the above code.So that my results will show in different lines in the pdf.   .join('\n')